# Asynchronous patterns in go

Tags: go

Recently I was checking backend code examples and I see that people are executing DB queries in synchronous fashion, for example:

```
result, err := db.Exec(stmt, title, content)
```

Coming from a Nodejs background, this bothers me a bit

I understand that http handlers are pretty much a go routine, but won't this block entire thread until DB sends back a response?

Is there any asynchronous design pattern to address this problem?
Or maybe this is just a way it is in go?

Comment: It will block only that gouroutine, and another goroutine will be immediately scheduled. A similar thing will happen in Node.

Comment: "but won't this block entire thread" - Go runtime is not like the event loop in node.js. If you're using goroutines, there is no one single thread that can be blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that http handlers are pretty much a go routine, but won't this block entire thread until DB sends back a response?

No. Go is not Node. There is no reason to think about blocking/nonblocking in Go as threads don't get blocked by "blocking" code as in Node.

> Is there any asynchronous design pattern to address this problem?

No, because there *is* no problem.

> Or maybe this is just a way it is in [Go]?

Exactly.